# How to return Single.error() when one of sources in Single.zip fails?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-java2

I have two sources of Singles, which I combine into one Single of Pair.

Let's say we have two methods for these sources:

```
private Single<String> single1() {} 
private Single<String> single2() {}
```

Now I combine them into `Single<Pair<String, String>`

```
private Single<Pair<String, String> combineSingles() {
    Single.zip(single1(), single2(), BiFunction<String, String, Pair<String, String>>) (t1, t2) -> new Pair(t1, t2))
}
```

When one of the methods (single1 or single2) returns Single.error(), I get `UndeliverableException` cause error isn't handled in zip operator. I want instead to return `Single.error()` from `combineSingles()` method, how can I achieve that?

Comment: What is the exact stacktrace of that `UndeliverableException`?

Answer (score 7):

try this

```
private Single<Pair<String, String> combineSingles() {
    try {
        Single.zip(single1(), single2(), BiFunction<String, String, Pair<String, String>>) (t1, t2) -> new Pair(t1, t2))
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Single.error()
    }
}
```

by the way i was first to suggest the try catch method :)

Comment: it will catch all the thrown errors, and its up to you to handle them the way you wish, you could try catching multiple exceptions with this method.

Answer (score 2):

`onErrorResumeNext(...)` is your friend, which is the try/catch equivalent for RxJava.

Here is the complete example

```
public final class RxTest {

    private static Single<String> single1() {
        return Single.just("1");
    }
    private static Single<String> single2() {
        return Single.error(new RuntimeException("single2"));
    }

    private static Single<Pair<String, String>> combineSingles() {
        return Single.zip(single1(), single2(), Pair::new)
                .onErrorResumeNext(Single.error(new RuntimeException("zip")));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        combineSingles()
                .test()
                .assertError(RuntimeException.class)
                .assertError(throwable -> "zip".equals(throwable.getMessage()));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

How about the usual try/catch logic?

```
Single<String> single1;
try {
    single1 = single1();
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
    return Single.error();
}
Single<String> single2;
try {
    single2 = single2();
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
    return Single.error();
}
return Single.zip(single1, single2, BiFunction<String, String, Pair<String, String>>) (t1, t2) -> new Pair(t1, t2))
```

Or if you want to *replace* the faulty value with `Single.error()`, then

```
Single<String> single1;
try {
    single1 = single1();
} catch (RuntimeException e) {
    single1 = Single.error();
}
```

And so on.

Comment: I don't think you understand my problem, I think code will crash for the same reason, cause I didn't handle error in zip operator

Comment: @ThirdMartian Well, you said that one of the *methods* `single1()`/`single2()` may fail. In my code, their invocations are wrapped with try/catch. If another exception will arise in `zip()` method, it will not be handled, that's true.

Comment: Yep, my fault, I'll edit my question to explain it better.